# Custom images layout in gallery

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, smarty

I need to arrange my gallery this way:

[image: my gallery]


I thought about something like this:
[image]

BUT! There is a huge problem. Saying nothing of my good Bootstrap knowledge, I need to use it in 'shoper' which is an e-commerce tool. It's using smarty to get products and in loop show them in the way I like.

The code looks like this:

```
// huge example

{foreach product......}
  <img src="product-n" />
  <span>Product-n Title</span>
{/foreach}
```

It is really hard to arrange images in bootstrap, using smarty (or any other loop).

I know my post doesn't contain a lot of info about it, but let me know what should I say, so you guys can help me.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyLydN This is your grid. You have to check if row is even or odd and use different template.

Comment: With the iteration property, this should be easy to handle http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.iteration

Comment: @makshh I know how to create it. but I need it to be built in a loop